# Preview Data URI in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, uri, webstorm, developer-tools

Our company has a lot of image uris hard coded in Javascript. This is all well and good, but when I am interacting with code I sometimes would like to take a quick peek at what the image looks like. Does anyone have any tips for how to do this efficiently, especially from within an IDE such as WebStorm?

These images are assigned to variables in JavaScript like so:
"url('data:image/png;base64,someImageData')"

Comment: Are these images being viewed within a webpage? If so, can you provide a generic construction of how they are being provided

Answer (score 2):

If your images are referenced from HTML using  tag, Shift+mouse hover over the URL will show image preview